# Filter ng-repeat items based on numeric conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to use a select menu to filter items based on greater than/less than conditional.

**HTML:**

```
        <select name="likes-filter" id="likes-filter" class="form-control" data-ng-model="filterValue">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="10">&gt; 10</option>
            <option value="20">&gt; 20</option>
            <option value="50">&gt; 50</option>
            <option value="100">&gt; 100</option>
            <option value="500">&gt; 500</option>
            <option value="1000">&gt; 1000</option>
        </select>

    <div class="image-container" data-ng-repeat="image in images | filter: filterValue | orderBy: dateSubmitted">

        <div class="like-wrapper">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
            <p>{{image.likes}}</p>
        </div>

        <p class="date">{{image.dateSubmitted | date: 'medium'}}</p>

        <img data-ng-src="{{image.path}}" alt="Image">
        <span class="btn" data-ng-click="confirmImageDelete(image)">&times;</span>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.images = [
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "/images/profile-placeholder-250x250.gif",
        likes: 5
    },
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "/images/profile-placeholder-250x250.gif",
        likes: 9
    }];
```

So I want the select menu to filter the images repeat based on a greater than like count.

So something like `<option value="likes > 10">&gt; 10</option>` Would filter my ng-repeat and show only images with a greater than 10 like count.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to filter your images. Try this snippet:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.filterValue = 10;
  $scope.images = [
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "http://www.blinkawards.com/Images/profilePhoto.gif",
        likes: 5
    },
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "http://www.blinkawards.com/Images/profilePhoto.gif",
        likes: 9
    },
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "http://www.blinkawards.com/Images/profilePhoto.gif",
        likes: 90
    },
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "http://www.blinkawards.com/Images/profilePhoto.gif",
        likes: 190
    },
    {
        dateSubmitted: new Date(),
        path: "http://www.blinkawards.com/Images/profilePhoto.gif",
        likes: 1009
    }];
    
    $scope.filterByLikes = function(image) {
        return image.likes > parseInt($scope.filterValue);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
<select name="likes-filter" id="likes-filter" class="form-control" data-ng-model="filterValue">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="10">&gt; 10</option>
            <option value="20">&gt; 20</option>
            <option value="50">&gt; 50</option>
            <option value="100">&gt; 100</option>
            <option value="500">&gt; 500</option>
            <option value="1000">&gt; 1000</option>
        </select>

    <div class="image-container" data-ng-repeat="image in images | filter: filterByLikes | orderBy: dateSubmitted">

        <div class="like-wrapper">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
            <p>{{image.likes}}</p>
        </div>

        <p class="date">{{image.dateSubmitted | date: 'medium'}}</p>

        <img data-ng-src="{{image.path}}" alt="Image" width="30px">
        <span class="btn" data-ng-click="confirmImageDelete(image)">&times;</span>
    </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel like I made this way harder than it should have been haha.